# solve this equation $1 = \small\left( \frac{\mu}{f} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \left( 1+ \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 \right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I am supposed to solve $1 = \left( \frac{\mu}{f} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \left( 1+ \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 \right)$
iteratively for $\mu$ and am supposed to get

$$\mu = f \left(1 - \frac{\pi^2}{12} \left( \frac{kT}{f} \right)^2\right).$$

Unfortunately, I don't quite see how this iteration is meant to work. Does anybody here have an idea how it is possible to get this solution?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

$$1 = \left( \frac{\mu}{f} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \left( 1+ \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 \right)$$
$$\mu = f \left( 1+ \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 \right)^{-2/3}$$
It is supposed that the term $\alpha=\frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 $ is smaller than $1$.

In a first and rough approximation we have $\mu\simeq f$ and $\alpha \simeq \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{f} \right)^2 $

The second (a bit better) approximate comes from

$$(1+\alpha)^{-2/3}\simeq 1-\frac{2}{3}\alpha$$

wich leads to :
$$\mu \simeq f \left(1 - \frac{2}{3} \frac{\pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{f} \right)^2\right) = f \left(1 - \frac{\pi^2}{12} \left( \frac{kT}{f} \right)^2\right)$$

This is the expected formula, which is, in fact, a step in an iterative process, in order to obtain an even better approximate. If necessary, the next step would be to use more terms in the series expansion of $(1+\alpha)^{-3/2}$ and to use the approximate of $\mu$ already obtained to put it into  $\alpha \simeq \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu} \right)^2 $ instead of $\mu\simeq f$.

In a numerical iterative process (of course, without explicitely writting the successive formulas which become very big), it is even simpler to use the recurence equation :
$$\mu_{n+1} = f \left( 1+ \frac{ \pi^2}{8} \left( \frac{kT}{\mu_n} \right)^2 \right)^{-2/3}$$
Starting from $\mu_1=f$ and at each step, replace in it the numerical value of $\mu$ computed at the preceeding step. This avoids the deviation due to the limited series expansion of $(1+\alpha)^{-2/3}$